# What do the symbols in The Witcher: Blood Origin mean?

Tags: the-witcher, the-witcher-blood-origins

In the Netflix miniseries *The Witcher: Blood Origin* there is a symbol at the start of each episode. What do these symbols mean?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "[What Do the Symbols in The Witcher: Blood Origin Mean? (Opening & Closing Scenes"](https://fictionhorizon.com/what-do-the-symbols-in-the-witcher-blood-origin-mean-opening-and-closing-scenes/)